# ImportError: No module named int64

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, importerror, int64

I am trying to read a file using pickle.

Note: The file was created by reading records from mongodb and then stored in a file using pickle.

However I am getting the error

> ImportError: No module named int64

I looked for solution online, But issues is not resolved.

Code for accessing the file:

```
import pickle
infile = open('grp_event','r')

grp_event = pickle.load(infile)
infile.close()
for group in grp_event:
    print grp_event[group]
```

Comment: You need to use `cPickle` in python 2.7 if you want to use int64.